# How to form a MySQL query with 2 different ORDER BY statements

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a sort of Facebook-esque Like/Dislike system on my website and am using the following query to grab the likes + dislikes of a specific post:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts WHERE cid='$cid' AND pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids)." ORDER BY time DESC
```

`$pid` is an array of post ids to be searching for.

`zbid` is the id of the user who is currently accessing the page. Now, if that user has rated (liked/disliked) the post his result should be returned first, and then after that order the results by `time DESC`.

How would I go about modifying the query to do this?

If the `posts` table has the following data:

```
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| id | cid | zbid | pid | rating | time |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1    | 1   | 1      | 1    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 2  | 1   | 2    | 1   | -1     | 4    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 3  | 1   | 3    | 2   | 1      | 2    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 4  | 2   | 4    | 1   | -1     | 3    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 5  | 1   | 5    | 1   | 1      | 8    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 6  | 1   | 6    | 1   | -1     | 7    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
```

The current select statement (above) will return the following information (with `$pid = array(1);`):

```
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| id | cid | zbid | pid | rating | time |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 5  | 1   | 5    | 1   | 1      | 8    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 6  | 1   | 6    | 1   | -1     | 7    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 2  | 1   | 2    | 1   | -1     | 4    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 4  | 2   | 4    | 1   | -1     | 3    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1    | 1   | 1      | 1    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
```

However, if the person with `zbid=4` is accessing the page, it should bump that result (if it exists) up to the top as below:

```
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| id | cid | zbid | pid | rating | time |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 4  | 2   | 4    | 1   | -1     | 3    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 5  | 1   | 5    | 1   | 1      | 8    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 6  | 1   | 6    | 1   | -1     | 7    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 2  | 1   | 2    | 1   | -1     | 4    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
| 1  | 1   | 1    | 1   | 1      | 1    |
+----+-----+------+-----+--------+------+
```

The variable `$zbid` is set to the user's `zbid` who is accessing the page.

Comment: Please edit your question again, and add some sammple data and the desired output of that data after the query, so it's a little more clear what you're trying to do. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather rough solution I could come out with, using the information you provided:

**Solution 1 - The portable way**

```
-- This query will return User's posts and give it a higher priority in ordering, via post_order field
SELECT 
  posts.*
  ,0 as post_order
FROM posts
WHERE
  (cid='$cid' AND pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids).") AND
  (zbid = $user_zbid)

UNION ALL

-- This query will return everything BUT User's posts and give it a lower priority in ordering
SELECT 
  posts.*
  ,1 as post_order
FROM posts
WHERE
  (cid='$cid' AND pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids).") AND
  (zbid <> $user_zbid)
ORDER BY
  post_order -- This clause will put User's posts before the others
  ,time DESC
```

**Solution 2 - The more performing way (credits to [cbranch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333127/cbranch) for the suggestion)**

```
SELECT 
  posts.*
  ,IF(zbid = $user_zbid, 0, 1) as post_order
FROM posts
WHERE
  (cid='$cid' AND pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids).")
ORDER BY
  post_order -- This clause will put User's posts before the others
  ,time DESC
```

**Notes**
- As you may have noticed, I removed the DISTINCT from the SELECT, as I couldn't see a reason for them. Since you just extract data from a single table, you shouldn't have duplicates. Obviously, you can still add them back, but remember not to use such clause unless it's really needed.
- The second query will be very expensive to run, as it uses the "not equal to" clauses. This means it won't be using indexes, and it won't be suitable for big amounts of data. In case you have to deal with a big table, this solution will have to be reviewed.

Comment: I think you could do the same thing with a single query and avoid the `UNION ALL`.  `SELECT IF(zbid = $user_zbid, 0, 1) AS post_order`

Comment: That's true, but it would be less portable. I tend to stick to ANSI SQL as much as I can. :)
However, the `IF()` clause would avoid the nasty "not equal to" clause, which would be a great advantage.

Comment: @cbranch I edited the answer adding your suggestion, together with due credits.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will be using this on a relatively large table so am opting for the first solution. I've never used `UNION`before so am unfamiliar with its syntax. Is the first solution the entire query or does it need to be appended to my current query?

Comment: @Keir Actually, the second solution might be faster on very large tables, although less portable.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing Diego's suggestion I came up with the following answer that has worked:

```
SELECT zbid,pid,rating,0 as post_order,time
    FROM posts
    WHERE cid='$cid'
        AND (pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids).")
        AND zbid!='$zbid'
UNION
SELECT zbid,pid,rating,1 as post_order,time
    FROM posts
    WHERE cid='$cid'
        AND (pid=".implode(" OR pid=",$pids).")
        AND zbid='$zbid'
ORDER BY
    post_order DESC,
    time DESC
```